# how to show a part of a string that starts with a certain character and ends with a cetain character in php?

Tags: php

i want to get only 40 from the below string but it can change to any value like 30, 5, 2, x, y x the the string in parenthesis is constant except the integer which is a variable. so the solution is to remove the sub-string that starts with "(" and ends with ")" and echo out everything else? how to do this i tried using substring and strpos but couldnt find the the perfect solution? can anyone help me here

```
$string = "40 (In Stock: 1)";
```

i have tried using

```
<?php
$stock = "40 (instock: 50)";
$replace_string =  substr($stock, strpos($stock, "("), strpos($stock, ")"));
echo str_replace($replace_string,"",$stock);
?>
```

but is there any other alternative?

Comment: `list($res,) = explode('(', $str,2);`

Comment: perfect situation for a preg_match!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not using a regex?

```
$string = "40 (In Stock: 1)";
$matches = array();
$pattern = '/(\d+) \(.*?\)/';
if(preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches))
{
     echo $matches[1]; // Prints 40
}
```

Comment: Looking Great but can you tell me how does the patter '/(\d+) \(.*?\)/' works?

Comment: Sure, the pattern itself is inside the slashes: \d+ means to find multiple decimals. As it is written in round brackets, the match is stored. Then follows the pattern " (anything)". The brackets are escaped with a backslashes. ".*?" is a greedy search matching anything until the closed bracket.

Comment: still not clear, i mean you are setting the pattern  inside '//' and how you are getting "(" and ")" ?

Comment: You really should dig into regex basics. Look at this: "/(DECIMALS+) \(ANYTHING\)/". Where "/" is at the beginning and the end to tell beeing a regex. Anything matching(!) written in () will be stored into the matches array. Some characters like brackets are control characters, so if you want to find such one, you need to escape with preceeding a backslash. The ".*?" is the magic for matching anything until the next char of the pattern which is a closing bracket. Google for "perlre perltut" to learn basics.

Comment: thanks for the explation, can you give me a reference where i can find more about regex, i actually never did the regex before, php manual is not really helpful in regex as i just saw give me something beginner friendly reference if you have... :)